# Setup C# and F# notebooks on Jupyter hosted by Binder

Tags: c#, .net, docker, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile

Hi all I want to make use the new  .NET Jupyter Notebooks, so I prepare a repo on git with a `dockerfile` (which is right) and a `NuGet.config` file like this tuto:

[here the tuto](https://github.com/dotnet/try/blob/master/CreateBinder.md?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha)

and everything its ok, but when a want to use my c# or f# kernel theres no way because it doesnt exist!!

[image]

But if i see the logs on the docker image:

[image: DockerFile]

So my DockerFile is right but it cannot loaded on the web, also conda give me that there are avaliable ones on local:

[image]

My question is if Jupyter doesnt allow you to use `dotnet` commands how I will install it?- From your Docker Image. 
Ok yes but not at all, because its succesfully builted but not loaded?, is the path wrong?
Is there a way to tell jupyter some like "Please look at here"??

*EDIT* :

[image: So if you check the place where it looks for kernel theres only one]

So if you check the place where it looks for kernel theres only one.

Going to do it manually but not sure...its going to be losed after ended the session isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed, there´s a problem explicited on the Binder Docs:

```
Here’s an example of a Dockerfile FROM statement that would work.

FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook:cf6258237ff9

The following examples would not work:

FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook
or
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook:latest
```

So you need to specify a concrete image, and I used the last updated one:
[image]

And this is how must start the dockerfile(must? not sure but it works for me)

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook:45f07a14b422
```

And it will built it right and without problemas and when you click your badge it will display:
[image]